# Rails: increment in a datetime column in all tables

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have 20 tables and every table has column `updated_at` I want to update all the rows in all the tables such as every row's `updated_at` column should increase 1 hour.

How can I do it with avoiding to update active records object I would prefer to run a SQL query instead on every table one query for one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to help others here is how was I able to get this solve

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE users SET created_at = created_at + INTERVAL '3600 seconds'")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask this question in the database admin section of SO I think you'll get a much better response.

I tried googling and can find:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

> SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, '2017/08/25') AS DateAdd;

So in your case, if it's called updated_at and the table is users:

```
SELECT UpdatedAt, DATEADD(hour, 1, UpdatedAt) AS DateAdd FROM Employees;
```

I'm pretty crap at SQL but I think that should make sense.

If it doesn't work, repost this to the database section and you'll have people who know what they're talking about helping you :)

Comment: postgresql does not provide DATEADD function.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via the Rails console without actually instantiating the `ActiveRecord` objects if you use `update_columns`

You should be able to do:

```
YourThing.find_each do |thing|
  new_time = thing.updated_at + 1.hour
  thing.update_columns(updated_at: new_time)
end
```

That will bypass validation and all callbacks, so it should run pretty quickly, depending on the number of records you're working with.

Here's the documentation for `update_columns`: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns

Comment: Thanks! but I have idea of `update_column` but it will required to loop on each record and I have billions of records and this approach will take too much time to complete.