# Increment in column for all records in one query with mongodb and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181871/rails-increment-in-a-datetime-column-in-all-tables/55184518#55184518) but same thing I need to do with mongodb how can I add increase every single record's created_at column. For example I have three records with timestamp 1,5 and 20 I want increment by 5 and these would become 6,10,25 respectively in one query. The purpose is to avoid loop for thousands of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#inc) operator from mongodb

**Rails usage**

```
CollectionName.collection.update_many({query}, {"$inc": {"field_name": value_to_inc_with}})
```

Comment: Thanks @ashusvirus but I'm getting `undefined method `update' for #<Mongo::Collection:0x00007f67c5dd16a0>`